# Spring 3.1.1 RedirectUtils equivalent in Spring 3.2.4

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, spring-security

Am using org.springframework.security.util.RedirectUtils in spring 3.1.1 Now we are upgrading to spring 3.2.4 Am wondering is there any Spring 3.1.1 RedirectUtils equivalent in Spring 3.2.4

```
if (System.currentTimeMillis() - session.getCreationTime() > getMaxSessionTimeToLive())     {
                RedirectUtils.sendRedirect(request, response, ApplicationUrlConfig.SPRING_LOGOUT_URL, false);
                return;
            }
            else if (request.getSession().getAttribute(IS_URL_VERIFIED) == null) {
                String targetURL = successHandler.onSuccess(authentication, request);

                if (!AuthenticationModeEnum.LOCAL.toString().equalsIgnoreCase(authMode)
                        &&   (targetURL.endsWith(applicationUrlConfig.getChangePasswordUrl()) || targetURL
                                .endsWith(request.getContextPath() +  applicationUrlConfig.getWelcomeUrl()))) {
                    targetURL = applicationUrlConfig.getEndUserIndexUrl();
                }
                if (!(applicationUrlConfig.getEndUserIndexUrl().equals(targetURL) || applicationUrlConfig
                        .getAdminIndexUrl().equals(targetURL))) {
                    RedirectUtils.sendRedirect(request, response, targetURL, false);
                }
```

Comment: I'm pretty sure class pre-dates Spring Security 3, so I'm not sure where you're getting it from in 3.1.1.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`RedirectUtils` was a Spring Security 2 class. From 3.0 onwards classes use a `RedirectStrategy` implementation in preference as customization of redirect behaviour was a common request.

The [`DefaultRedirectStrategy`](http://docs.spring.io/spring-security/site/docs/3.2.3.RELEASE/apidocs/org/springframework/security/web/DefaultRedirectStrategy.html) has essentially the same behaviour as `RedirectUtils.sendRedirect`.